# Jquery only updating elements in the first matching div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two matching div that are siblings, they each have 2 images in them. I have one image showing in each sibling div by default and the other hidden. I then have a control to click to hide the current image and show the other.

My problem is that only the images in the first div are updating, the images in the second div are not changed.

I'm being fairly generic in my traversal, not a lot of specific classes, and I need to keep it that way.

Feels like I'm missing something really simple or maybe I'm not understanding how .eq() works in some way that limits the change to the first ".images" div?

How can I fix this to have the images in both divs change at the same time?

My html is is basically:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="image-group">
    <h2> Title </h2>

    <div class="color-selection">
        <img alt="Black and Red" title="Black and Red">
        <img alt="Black and Matte Black" title="Black and Matte Black">
    </div>

    <div class="images">
        <img style="display: inline;">    
        <img style="display: none;">   
   </div>

   <div class="images">
        <img style="display: inline;">    
        <img style="display: none;">
   </div>

  </div><!--end image group -->

  <div class="image-swap">
    <i class="js-profile current">View 1</i>
    <i class="js-angle">View 2</i>
  </div>
</div><--/end main -->
```

And the jquery:

```
 $(document).on("click" , ".js-profile" , function(){

 var itemImage = $(this).parent().prev().find(".images img");

 $(itemImage).eq(1).fadeOut(200);
 $(itemImage).eq(0).fadeIn(200);

 $(this).addClass("current");
 $(this).next().removeClass("current");

 return false;

 })


 $(document).on("click" , ".js-angle" , function(){

 var itemImage = $(this).parent().prev().find("images img");

 $(itemImage).eq(0).fadeOut(200);
 $(itemImage).eq(1).fadeIn(200);

 $(this).addClass("current");
 $(this).prev().removeClass("current");

 return false;
 })
```

Comment: Console log error `Uncaught ReferenceError: itemImage is not defined`, I would debug that first.

Comment: you need to change var bikeImage to var itemImage.

Comment: Thanks, errors were generated buy trying to sanitize the code before posting. Edited post to reflect the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have some naming issues:

```
var bikeImage = $(this).parent().prev().find("images img");
$(itemImage).eq(0).fadeOut(200);
```

It should be

```
var itemImage = $(this).parent().prev().find(".images img");
$(itemImage).eq(0).fadeOut(200);
```

Let's asume that's due to posting it there and concentrate on the main problem.

```
$(this).parent().prev().find(".images img");
```

This returns a set of four images, always, not some 2x2 matrix, so

```
$(itemImage).eq(0).fadeOut(200);
$(itemImage).eq(1).fadeIn(200);
```

This part always targets the first set of images, as they have indexes 0 and 1, the other two images have indexes 2 and 3. So yes, `eq` does something else than you expect because your selection is different than what you might think.

Simple solution would be to filter then like this

```
$(itemImage).filter(':first-child').fadeOut(200);
$(itemImage).filter(':last-child').fadeIn(200);
```

This again takes a set of 4 images but doesn't limit the query to index 0 or 1 but rather to `first-child`, so it gets first image of both subset.

Comment: After I posted I went back to the code and ditched `:eq()` to use `:nth-child() ` and basically ended up with your solution using `:nth` instead of `:eq`. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

`itemImage` will be an array of count 4

by `eq(0)` and `eq(1)` you are targeting only img tag in your first div

For the second div it should be `eq(2)` and `eq(3)`

Also there is a scope issue for `var itemImage` This variable is not accessible in the event handler `$(document).on("click" , ".js-angle" , function(){...}`

The below code should work for you.

```
 $(document).on("click" , ".js-profile" , function(){

 var itemImage = $(this).parent().prev().find(".images:first img"); // this line is updated

 $(itemImage).eq(1).fadeOut(200);
 $(itemImage).eq(0).fadeIn(200);

 $(this).addClass("current");
 $(this).next().removeClass("current");

 return false;

 })


 $(document).on("click" , ".js-angle" , function(){

 var bikeImage = $(this).parent().prev().find("images:nth-child(2) img"); // this line is updated

 $(bikeImage).eq(0).fadeOut(200); // itemImage changed to bikeImage 
 $(bikeImage).eq(1).fadeIn(200);  // itemImage changed to bikeImage 

 $(this).addClass("current");
 $(this).prev().removeClass("current");

 return false;
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... maybe I'm not understanding how .eq() works in some way that limits the change to the first ".images" div?

You are correct. Please refer to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) for `.eq()`:

> *Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.*

This means you are only selecting the first image element in the jQuery collection, not the first element in each div.

To resolve this you should use the [`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) pseudo-selector as follows:

```
$(itemImage).filter(':nth-child(1)').fadeOut(200);
$(itemImage).filter(':nth-child(2)').fadeIn(200);
```

According to the jQuery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) for `:first-child`, it can also be used in place of `:nth-child(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).on("click" , ".js-profile" , function(){

 var itemImage = $(this).parent().prev().find(".images");

 itemImage.each(function(){
 $(this).find('img').eq(1).fadeOut(200);
 });
itemImage.each(function(){
    $(this).find('img').eq(0).fadeIn(200);
 });
 $(this).addClass("current");
 $(this).next().removeClass("current");

 return false;

 })


 $(document).on("click" , ".js-angle" , function(){
 var itemImage = $(this).parent().prev().find(".images");

 itemImage.each(function(){
 $(this).find('img').eq(0).fadeOut(200);
 });
itemImage.each(function(){
    $(this).find('img').eq(1).fadeIn(200);
 });

 $(this).addClass("current");
 $(this).prev().removeClass("current");

 return false;
 })
```

```css
.images img:first-child{
    
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ccc;
    
}

.images img{
    
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#f00;
    
}
.image-swap{
    padding:5px;
    
}
.image-swap i{
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.image-swap i:hover{
    
     background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="image-group">
    <h2> Title </h2>

    <div class="color-selection">
        <img alt="Black and Red" title="Black and Red">
        <img alt="Black and Matte Black" title="Black and Matte Black">
    </div>

    <div class="images">
        <img style="display: inline;">    
        <img style="display: none;">   
   </div>

   <div class="images">
        <img style="display: inline;">    
        <img style="display: none;">
   </div>

  </div><!--end image group -->

  <div class="image-swap">
    <i class="js-profile current">View 1</i>
    <i class="js-angle">View 2</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this Helps..